# Chaning Ruby regexp operators

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm writing a filter program that reads a CSV file containing address data and excludes rows that are located in a crescent (cres), avenue (ave) or place (pl).

Here's some example input:

```
data = <<CSV
ID,Street address,Town,Valuation date,Value
1,1 Northburn RD,WANAKA,1/1/2015,280000
2,1 Mount Ida PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,280000
3,1 Mount Linton AVE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,780000
4,1 Centre CRES,WANAKA,1/1/2015,295000
CSV

require 'csv'

elements = []
CSV.parse(data, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
  elements << row.to_h
end
elements
#=> [
#     {:id=>"1", :street_address=>"1 Northburn RD", :town=>"WANAKA", :valuation_date=>"1/1/2015", :value=>"280000"},
#     {:id=>"2", :street_address=>"1 Mount Ida PL", :town=>"WANAKA", :valuation_date=>"1/1/2015", :value=>"280000"},
#     {:id=>"3", :street_address=>"1 Mount Linton AVE", :town=>"WANAKA", :valuation_date=>"1/1/2015", :value=>"780000"},
#     {:id=>"4", :street_address=>"1 Centre CRES", :town=>"WANAKA", :valuation_date=>"1/1/2015", :value=>"295000"}
#   ]
```

I can use simple regular expressions to filter for one of the three, i.e. `/pl/`, `/cres/` and `/ave/`, but I can't chain them using `&&`: (nor do they function when I split them into three separate "filters")

```
elements.select { |e| e[:street_address].downcase! !~ /pl/ && e[:street_address].downcase! !~ /cres/ && e[:street_address].downcase! !~ /ave/ }
#=> [
#     {:id=>"1", :street_address=>"1 northburn rd", :town=>"WANAKA", :valuation_date=>"1/1/2015", :value=>"280000"},
#     {:id=>"3", :street_address=>"1 mount linton ave", :town=>"WANAKA", :valuation_date=>"1/1/2015", :value=>"780000"},
#     {:id=>"4", :street_address=>"1 centre cres", :town=>"WANAKA", :valuation_date=>"1/1/2015", :value=>"295000"}
#   ]
```

This filters out entry #2 as expected, but not #3 and #4.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Is the code to read the CSV file relevant to your question? (you should use Ruby's [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) library by the way)

Comment: No it isn't, works perfectly fine. Just the filter portion is dodgy, but I thought I'd include everything just in case :)

I'll look into the CSV library too!

Comment: It's usually better to post code that others can just copy-and-paste. Could you add some example data for `elements` and the expected output?

Comment: hey Stefan, added some CSV data.
Expected output would just exclude rows with addresses ending in CRES/PL/AVE

Comment: I've edited your question so the example can be easily run (and also incorporated the neat CSV library - use it!).

Comment: thanks for all your help man

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of `downcase!` - it alters the receiver and it returns `nil` if no changes were made.

```
str = 'FOO'
str.downcase! #=> "foo"
str.downcase! #=> nil
```

Therefore, your second comparison becomes `nil !~ /cres/` which is always `true`.

To fix your code, use `downcase` (without `!`):

```
elements[:streetAddress].downcase !~ /pl/
```

or add a `i` to your regular expression to make it case-insensitive:

```
elements[:streetAddress] !~ /pl/i
```

Furthermore, you can combine your regular expressions and use [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-reject):

```
elements.reject { |e| e[:streetAddress] =~ /pl|cres|ave/i }
```

To only match strings that *end* with "pl", "cres", or "ave", use an appropriate [anchor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors), for example `/(pl|cres|ave)$/i`

Comment: that...is a decent point...so would I do three seperate upcase/downcase conversions? That seems a bit backward to me.

Comment: @TinusWagner of course not, I've updated my answer with an alternative.

Comment: you sir are a legend. Thank you.

Comment: Be aware that 'Crescent ST', 'Plane BVD' and stuff like this will match the regex. Consider adding \z to the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove elements from an array based on a condition, the idiomatic way might be to use [Array#delete_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-delete_if)

IMO, try not to use regex when you already know which values are accepted. Regex are great at pattern matching (checking email validity and such), but their use should not go farther.

Assuming RD, CRES, AVE are always on the last word, this works :

```
x = elements.delete_if do |el|
  ['pl', 'cres', 'ave'].include?(el[:streetAddress].downcase.split.last)
end
```

Comment: hey floum, if we simply use 'pl' for instance as an remove condition then it won't work if the full string for streetAddress is "55 Mt Gold AVE" for instance right?

Comment: I saw you submitted data from CSV right after I answered. I must check for that and get back to you in a few.